# Is it okay to use the same webdriver for all of my steps in cucumber selenium? and how

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I want to create a base step, that logs into two websites using two drivers. i then want all of the following tests to inherit the same drivers to carry out the rest of the steps (navigating to different pages, etc). is this a bad idea? i have done this using testng already but now im trying to convert my project into a cucumber one (not sure if i can use testng and cucumber together).the reason for doing this is because it makes the test runs a lot faster.

Comment: The quickest way would be to use two static fields. You can use Cucumbers before all/after all hooks to intitialize the fields.

Comment: @teaaa you mean the same driver **instance** across all the tests?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje
is this good practice? is it better to just create a new driver for new scenarios?

Comment: @AlexeyR. yes. basically i'd be making all of my features dependent on each other. so feature 1: request a new team feature 2: accept the new team. if these are two different features i don't understand how to have these in two different files - do i have feature 2 redo everything in feature 1 or can i just share the same driver and continue

Comment: I wouldn't do that because your tests won't be isolated (cookies caches, etc. will be preserved across the tests) so that you will pay the reliability for your increased speed.

Comment: @AlexeyR. so instead what do i do? in feature 2 do i just create a new team, or do i not test feature 1 and just test it together in one file? i'm using two different websites simultaneously with two different drivers.

Comment: You just create new driver for **each your scenario** and share it across steps within that scenario.

Comment: @teaaa it depends. With static fields you can't run tests in parallel and you have to be mindful about shared state. Without static fields you can, but you may not have the resources to run that many browsers. If so then there is nothing bad about reusing the same browser. As long as you do it understand the limitations and tradeoffs.